# Implementing shader animation for Windows Store DirectX App

Tags: windows-store-apps, hlsl, directx-11

I am trying to achieve shader animation in Windows Store DirectX App. Actually I just would like to achieve the same animation I see on below link (implemented for DirectX 9 and C#).

http://www.rastertek.com/dx10tut33.html

I am kind of able to find my way around with DirectX 11.1 (Windows Store App compatible DirectX shaders) but I can not see how may I pass the time parameter to the shader code from the C++ program logic so that I can affect shader state and have different effect based on the time.

Please share an opinion if you have some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass parameters to a shader you can use constantbuffers ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Shader_Constant_Buffer)). You create a constantbuffer, fill it with your data, e.g. the actual time, and set it in the desired shader with

```
   ID3D11DeviceContext::GSSetConstantBuffers
   ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetConstantBuffers
or ID3D11DeviceContext::VSSetConstantBuffers.
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I am looking for. Its name was somewhat misleading however. Do you know why these buffers are called constant?

Comment: Afaik because they describe data which are constant and so not changing between all shaderunits during your draw call :)